# How to save a specific name of generated xls file

Tags: vb.net

I use [this vb.net tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982/it) provided my Microsoft to create a xls file:

All is working good, but I want to save the file with a specific name instead of Cartel1.xls, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this code to the example.

```
    Dim file = oXL.GetSaveAsFilename()
    If file IsNot Nothing _
       AndAlso file.ToString().Length > 0 _
       AndAlso file.ToString() <> "False" Then
        oWB.SaveAs(file)
    End If
```

This code opens the Save As dialog of Excel, if you press Cancel then you get as result a boolean object with value FALSE. Instead if you type a file name you get, as result the full filename typed (path included). This file could be passed to the Worksheet method SaveAs to complete the save.

Using the code in the example I have added it at the end of the button_click method before the dispose of the Excel Application and the Excel Worksheet, but, of course you could call it wherever makes sense for you.